# Show another image when hovering over image

Tags: javascript, hover, gallery, lightbox, mouseover

I really like this pure [CSS gallery](http://host.sonspring.com/hoverbox/) ([explanation](http://sonspring.com/journal/hoverbox-image-gallery)).

How do I change this code so that it doesn't preload all the pictures that show on mouseover/hover? Any lightweight javascript or similar that I can use instead? (or simple wordpress plugin).

It is important that the image that shows on hover is right above the thumbnail just like the example above and that it shows a separate image (no resize).

I have searched for days and I can't find any lightbox that does the same so hope someone can help me, thanks.

Comment: Does anyone know any ready made solution (jquery/javascript/wordpress plugin) that does the same thing as this pure CSS gallery demo: http://host.sonspring.com/hoverbox? I have now searched for days! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would just use jquery, it would look something like,

```
<script>
$("thingtohover").hover(
function () {
$(this).append($("<span class='hovers'<img src=<'/path/to/img.jpg'")</span>);

},
,
function () {
$(this).find("span:last").remove();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, very much Mallen. I'm not good at this so how can I implement that so it looks just like the gallery in the link http://host.sonspring.com/hoverbox/ - I may be able to use your code for one picture but I'm lost when it comes to using this for a gallery. Also how do I position the hover image right above the thumbnail? 

Do you know of a ready made solution/plugin I could use?

Comment: The code above appends a <span> to the end of the element you want to add a hovering element to. It has a css class called 'hovers'. So you would have to use a css sheet with position:relative and width and height set to what you want.

Comment: Thanks again but I'm still confused about how I should implement it. Let's say that I have img1.jpg as the thumbnail and wants to show img1-big.jpg on hover. Next to that I have img2.jpg as thumbnail and img2-big.jpg on hover. How would that code look? I don't know jquery but I guess I don't have to repeat the code for each image, right?